# where does docker container run, docker daemon or host kernel?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I want to know where does docker container run, docker daemon or host kernel or anywhere else? And where does application in container run, container or host kernel or anywhere else?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A running docker container will be the same as any process or application running on the machine. 
It just executes in the userspace and interacts with the kernel like any other application using system calls.

The docker deamon is a process that manages docker containers. It is just the backend that handles docker commands executed by the docker client (command line tool).